# How to use standerror() in depmixS4

Tags: hmmlearn

`Summary(fittedmodel)` gives me the coefficients of covariance for transition matrics. I am also curious how to get stand error values. it looks like standerror(fittedmodel) can work for that. But I have problem to understand the results. For example, the summary() result of my model and the result of call `standardError(fm2a)`, but I do not understand the results of standardError() function.

code:

```
mod1 <- depmix(list(rt~1,corr~1),data=speed,transition=~Pacc,nstates=2,
family=list(gaussian(),multinomial("identity")),ntimes=c(168,134,137))

set.seed(3)
fmod1 <- fit(mod1)

standardError(fmod1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `depmixS4::standardError` function returns a data.frame with in the rows the parameters in the same order as when calling e.g. `getpars(fmod1)`. In the first column (`par`) you will find the parameter estimate, the second column `constr` you will find a code reflecting whether the estimate is on the bound of the parameter space (`bnd`), a fixed parameter (`fix`), or whether the parameter is included in the estimated standard error (`inc`). The third column (`se`) provides the estimated standard error for the included parameters. Standard errors for `bnd` or `fix` parameters can not be estimated, and hence the value is `NA`.